# No indication of attempt to run cron job

Tags: cron

I am running the latest Sentora version on an Ubuntu 14 server.

I created a cronjob which should run every five minutes but there's no indication of an attempt to run the cron job.

I have tried to follow instructions here: http://docs.sentora.org/?node=91 but looks like its a bit old because some files mentioned don't exist.

How can I get it to run or even know whether there was an attempt to execute it?

Here's how my cron table looks like

```
# CRON ID: 2
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * php -d suhosin.executor.func.blacklist="passthru, show_source, shell_exec, system, pcntl_exec, popen, pclose, proc_open, proc_nice, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_close, leak, apache_child_terminate, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, escapeshellcmd, escapeshellarg, exec" -d open_basedir="/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/:/var/sentora/temp/" /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/domain.com/transactions.php
```

## END CRON ID: 2

Comment: What does the cron table entry look like? What else have you tried? How are you ascertaining that the cron entry is not triggering?

Answer (score 0):

Run a job that takes a long time, like `sleep 60`, and look for it in your process list (`ps aux | grep sleep`).

Also you'll probably see entries in `/var/log/auth.log` when the cron job is started and stopped, like this for my `sleep 20` set to run at `26 11 * * *`:

```
Dec  9 11:26:01 computername CRON[3148]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
Dec  9 11:26:21 computername CRON[3148]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user username
```